# osm2pgsql Protobuf not Found: Centos

Tags: linux, makefile, configure

**The Problem:**

I have a program I am installing from source. When I run *./configure*, it stops saying *"no protobuf development libraries found"*, however, protobuf is installed on my system.

How do I specify the path to those libraries when I run ./configure?

*The program I am trying to install is osm2pgsql on CentOS 6.6.*

Comment: Depending on the program you're installing from source, it will likely have a --with-lib-name=/path/to/lib/ option at install time.  In short, it relies on what you're installing.

Comment: Maybe your problem is that you don't have `protobuf dev` package installed? It's not the same as installing protobuf libraries. See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/protobuf

Comment: I've already installed `protobuf-devel` unfortunately.  I pulled up `./configure --help` and it said to set the path using `PROTOBUF_LIB` variable. I followed their instructions and pointed the variable to the correct path and it's still not working. The full command I entered: `./configure PROTOBUF_LIB=/usr/lib64/`

Comment: The answer likely is not in `protobuf-devel`, but in the configuration script (unspecified) which you are attempting to use.  Most error messages would show up in the generated `config.log` file.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I fixed the problem fortunately.

**What Happened?:**

*osm2pgsql* uses *pkg-config* to point to dependent libraries. On *CentOS 7 pkg-config* uses this directory `/usr/share/pkgconfig/`. Within this directory there are `.pc` files for different programs. These files are used by pkg-config to show where libraries of certain programs are located. When you install *protobuf* from package manager or source the installation doesn't automatically let *pkg-config* know where the libraries are at via a *.pc* file.

**The Fix:**

Install *protobuf* from source from their *git* page. After you've ran make install there will be several .pc files within the cloned directory. You need to place these in `/usr/share/pkgconfig`. To do this run the following in the cloned directory:

```
sudo cp protobuf.pc* /usr/share/pkgconfig/
sudo cp protobuf-lite.pc* /usr/share/pkgconfig/
```

**Conclusion:**

Ta Da! Now go back to your osm2pgsql install folder and rerun `./configure`.